# How to access Fritz!Box menus hidden by the ISP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, fritzbox

I have the Fritz!Box 6660 Cable router. I want to disable the radar detection on my WiFi. The closest radars (police station) are over 5km away and I'm using 25% transmit power anyway. However, the radar detection setting is hidden by the ISP so each time I reboot the router, it takes almost 15 minutes to set the WiFi channel for the 5GHz band.

I will appreciate any help in order to solve this, either by uncovering the hidden menus or through Telnet, CLI, or SSH access.

Comment: in the us, per cisco, 36-48,149-165 are non-DFS channels, and won;t perform a radar detection. that said radar detection should only take 60s, so either you have a false radar detection, or you are mistaken about nearby radar usage. https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless-mobility/80211/213882-radar-detection-in-dynamic-frequency-sel.html

Comment: Thanks! In EU non-DFS channels are 36-60 and 149-157. Obviously in my case something seems to be wrong with the router setup because it takes equally long times to restart regardless of the channel chosen. The ISP has tried it with 3 different Fritzboxes and the behavior was the same. They agreed it is not the expected behavior and promised to investigate and come back. I never heard from them again which is why I'm now investigating other options.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hidden by the ISP, a disable option is just not implemented by the manufacturer. ["Radar detection"](https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-6660-Cable/1349_5-GHz-Wi-Fi-network-is-occasionally-disabled-radar-signal/) is a built-in "feature" that is required by law, so it is not possible to disable the detection phase after the reboot.

<del>As far as I know, this detection is restricted to channels 116-132, using lower (or higher) channels should take care of this problem.</del>

[According to the manufacturer](https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-6660-Cable/3599_DFS-wait-time-or-radar-detection-despite-using-channels-36-48/) switching to different frequencies does not help (although other 6660 users supposedly solved the problem this way):

> Only FRITZ!Box models with Zero Wait DFS (for example FRITZ!Box 7590, FRITZ!Box 6591 Cable) can avoid the DFS wait time.

The manufacturer says you need to use 2.4 GHz network until DFS wait time is over (see the first link: ["Radar detection"](https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-6660-Cable/1349_5-GHz-Wi-Fi-network-is-occasionally-disabled-radar-signal/)).

First you can/should verify this by disabling the 5GHz band altogether, the problem should disappear.

If you can't use 2.4GHz, you will need to set up an additional AP (connected via Ethernet), they are fairly inexpensive. Make sure there is no overlap in the bandwidth of both APs if they are set up inside each other's radius.

Comment: Indeed, DFS is a legal requirement. In EU where I live it applies to WAS/RLAN equipment for frequencies between 5470–5725 MHz (ch.100-136). However, I asked the national telecom authorities and they clarified that for short range devices used in enclosed spaces and e.i.r.p. less than 1W (my router qualifies as such) this requirement is waived. In any case, my Fritz!Box does not offer a possibility to choose channels 149 and 157 which are above 5725 MHZ; the highest one offered is 128. Also, if I choose channels below 100, at reboot, my router still takes an equally long time to establish WiFi.

Comment: This information should go into the question. Also see updates to my answer. What happens if you deactivate the 5GHz band altogether and just use 2.4?

Comment: Many thanks for your support. For reasons that are too long to be explained here, I actually need to keep the 2.4 band disabled and only use the 5 GHz.

Comment: This is also important information that should go into the question. In this case, you will probably need to setup an additional AP (connected via Ethernet), they are fairly inexpensive. Make sure there is no overlap in the bandwidth of both APs if they are set up inside each other's radius.